# Can we have integer values(1, 2) as roles and not "ROLE_USER/ROLE_ADMIN" for spring security?

Tags: spring-security

I am getting error when using values 1, 2 as roles in place of 'ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, etc'. Can't we use integer values as roles.

Comment: Why do you need 1,2 and 3. They really make no sense. ROLE_USER is still meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I already have a column in my table which is used for usertype and is of type 'Number' and it is having values 0,1,2 for different type of users. I have to use this table. This table should not be modified also. This was actually the requirement. So, is it possible to have these values as roles? If so, can you pls suggest for a solution.

Comment: You should be able to use 1,2,3 provided you use it as string. '1', '2', '3'. Let me know if you encounter error.

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have a UserDetailsService?

Comment: Tried givimg 1, 2, 3 as string also. Still facing the same issue. I'm seeing the below exception:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [2, 1]
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:156)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
 ... 53 more